# Como puedo ordenar la tabla donde se muestran los post de forma numérica?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo una tabla de custom post type que muestra unos campos personalizados y me gustaría poder organizar de mayor a menor la tabla cuando pincho en el nombre del campo, tal y como hace wordpress por defecto con la fecha de creación del post. Lo que tengo son 2 campos numéricos. Y lo cierto es que me reoriganiza, pero no lo hace bien. Y en la url parece indicarse bien.

¿Cual puede ser el problema?

```
function sortable_channel_columns_list( $columns ){

    return wp_parse_args( array(
        'channel_views'             => '_numb_views_field',
        'channel_spectators'  => '_numb_spectators_field'
    ), $columns );
}
add_filter('manage_edit-channel_sortable_columns', 'sortable_channel_columns_list');
```

He tomado como ejemplo a seguir:
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/sortable-date-user-registered-column.html

Comment: Prueba a poner indicaciones sobre orden dentro del array que le pasas a `wp_parse_args`, algo así más o menos: `$arrParams=array( 'channel_views'             => '_numb_views_field',  'channel_spectators'  => '_numb_spectators_field', ;'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'campo'); return wp_parse_args($arrParams, $columns ); //resto del código...` En `campo` debes poner el nombre del campo por el cual quieres ordenar, según tu contexto.

Comment: El campo por el que quiero que se ordene depende de donde haga click el usuario. Puede ser _numb_views_field ó _numb_spectators_field. Si necesito capturar donde hace click necesitaria del uso de ajax, no?

Comment: Es correcto, si quieres pasar algún dato de algo que ocurra en el cliente al servidor lo mejor sería usar Ajax, pasándole ese dato. El cual usarías entonces como parámetro dinámico en `$arrParams`. Algo así: `$arrParams=array( 'channel_views' => '_numb_views_field', 'channel_spectators' => '_numb_spectators_field', ;'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => $valorDesdeCliente);` De todos modos, prueba primero con algo escrito manualmente para verificar que funciona.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar correctamente, sigo teniendo las mismas filas que no se ordenan por el número.

Comment: He leido en algunos sitios como este https://www.ractoon.com/2016/11/wordpress-custom-sortable-admin-columns-for-custom-posts/ que es necesario que se modifique la query cuando es por un campo customizado. Pero me sucede exactamente lo mismo, algunas filas no las ordena.

Comment: Arreglado, gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Hacemos que sea organizable los siguientes campos del listado al hacer click sobre los nombres de los campos
function sortable_channel_columns_list( $columns ){
    $arrParams = array(
        'channel_views'             => '_numb_views_field',
        'channel_spectators'    => '_numb_spectators_field'
    );

    return wp_parse_args( $arrParams, $columns );
}
add_filter('manage_edit-channel_sortable_columns', 'sortable_channel_columns_list');


//Interceptamos la query e indicamos por que campos queremos que ordene
function audience_orderby_meta( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) ){
        switch( $orderby ) {
      case '_numb_views_field':
                $query->set('meta_key','_numb_views_field');
                $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
      break;
            case '_numb_spectators_field':
                $query->set('meta_key','_numb_spectators_field');
                $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num'); // or meta_value for strings
            break;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'audience_orderby_meta', 1 );
```